# Phpstorm with protactor unresolved functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, end-to-end

I`m using phpstorm with protactor for angular and for some reason the IDE doesnt recognize some

functions. but the functions is working fine when i`m running the test.

for example:

```
  element(by.buttonText('toggle')).click();

        expect(element(by.css('.net-fade')).getText()).
          toEqual('something');
      })
```

The IDE tell me that the method by.css is "unresolved function or method".

Someone know how to fix it?

Comment: this may help, although your issue might be more complicated: https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/configuring-javascript-libraries.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with PHPStorm, so this won't be a full-answer:

But I'd say the basic problem is that Protractor binary auto-inserts `protractor.js` and other dependencies into the environment for you. This is what gives you `by` (along with other helper variables `browser`, `element`, etc).

You may want to insert protractor.js yourself, you can find it in

```
node_modules/protractor/lib/protractor.js
```

(And again, I am unsure of how PHPStorm includes files, but you might want to only manually add `protractor.js` if it is not running in test mode. And to this end, you could set flag in protractors `onPrepare()` function to check against).